Urysohn's Lemma for $C^1[0,1]$?
I need a thing like Urysohn's Lemma for $C^1[0,1]$.
In Rudin's functional analysis book in the above of page 36, it is stated that such a function there is in $ C^{\infty}(\mathbb{ R}^n)$ but one of the neighborhoods is open while in Urysohn's Lemma on continuous functions, both the neighborhoods are close.
Could anyone guide me that I how to use page 36  for  $C^1[0,1]$?


Its open most likely because you don't really consider smooth functions on closed sets (not counting manifolds)

You can extend $f\in C^n[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by considering extension from left and right by polynomials of degree $n$ with given derivatives.

I don't know your mean, could you explain more?

If you let $F$ to be $f$ on $[0, 1]$ and a polynomial of degree $n$ on $(1, \infty)$ then you the right-side derivatives of $f$ at $1$ force the polynomial to be of certain form, if it is to be $n$ times differentiable at $1$

Ok , thank you very much .

So can I use Uryshon's lemma for $C^1[0,1]$?

Are you looking as to whether a specific statement is true? Or are you asking generally if there are similar results to Urysohn's lemma available on $C^{1}[0,1]$? Please make it more clear what you are looking for. It is also a good idea to include the statement from Rudin's functional analysis book for those who do not have access to the book.

@DeanMiller first, I ask if is there similar result to Uryshon's lemma on $C^1[0,1]$? Second, I ask how I can use of functional analysis Rudin's idea to  answer the first part ?

@OushinTanakara your case there is an analogous version of Urysohn's lemma for $C^{1}[0,1]$. The problem is that many people such as me may not own a copy of Rudin's functional analysis book, so you should really be including what Rudin is doing there in your question.

@Dean Miller Ok , but I don't understand how upload it

@OushinTanakara It's probably better if you type up the relevant part in LaTeX. If you do want to upload an image, there is a button in the row underneath "Body" when you are in editing mode.

There is the following analogue of Urysohn's lemma.

If $A$ and $B$ are two non-empty disjoint closed subsets of $[0,1]$, then there is $\phi \in C^{\infty}[0,1]$ such that $\phi (x) = 1$ for all $x\in A$, $\phi (x) = 0$ for all $x\in B$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$.

This clearly implies your result since every infinitely differentiable function on $[0,1]$ is continuously differentiable.
To show this, it is helpful to make use of the following statements or results within proofs from 1.46 in the book "Functional Analysis" by Rudin.

($\ast$) If $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ are concentric closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $B_{1}$ in the interior of $B_{2}$, then there exists $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $\phi (x) = 1$ for every $x\in B_{1}$, $\phi (x) = 0$ for every $x$ outside $B_{2}$, and $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.


($\ast\ast$) If $0 < a < b < \infty$, there is $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g(x) = 0$ for all $x < a$, $g(x) = 1$ for all $x > b$ and $0 \leq g \leq 1$.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty disjoint closed subsets of $[0,1]$. Then $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, they are compact. Given $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r > 0$, let $B[x,r] := \{y\in \mathbb{R} : |y - x| \leq r\}$. For each $x\in A$ choose $r_{x} > 0$ such
that $B[x,r_{x}] \cap B = \emptyset$. This can be done because $B$ is closed and $A\cap B = \emptyset$. Since $A$ is compact there is a (non-empty) finite set $F\subseteq A$ such that $A\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in F} B[x, r_{x}/2]$. Because of ($\ast$), for each $x\in F$ there is some $\phi_{x}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
\begin{equation}
\phi_{x}(y) = 1 \; \text{for all} \; y\in B[x, r_{x}/2], \; \phi_{x}(y) = 0 \; \text{for all} \; y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus B[x, r_{x}] \; \text{and} \; 0 \leq \phi_{x} \leq 1 .
\end{equation}
In particular, the weaker condition
\begin{equation}
\phi_{x}(y) = 1 \; \text{for all} \; y\in B[x, r_{x}/2], \; \phi_{x}(y) = 0 \; \text{for all} \; y\in B \; \text{and} \; 0\leq \phi_{x} \leq 1 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
holds for all $x\in F$. Now define $\tau := \sum_{x\in F} \phi_{x}$. It follows that
\begin{equation}
\tau \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \; \tau (x)\geq 1 \; \text{for all} \; x\in A, \; \tau (x) = 0 \; \text{for all} \; x\in B \; \text{and} \; \tau \geq 0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
by (1) and the inclusion $A\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in F} B[x, r_{x}/2]$.
By ($\ast\ast$), take $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g(x) = 0$ for all $x < 1/3$ and $g(x) = 1$ for all $x > 2/3$. Define $\phi := g \circ \tau$. It is straightforward to show, using (2) and the definition of $g$, that
\begin{equation}
\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \; \phi (x) = 1 \; \text{for all} \; x\in A, \; \phi (x) = 0 \; \text{for all} \; x\in B \; \text{and} \; 0 \leq \phi \leq 1.
\end{equation}
By restricting $\phi$ to $[0,1]$ the desired function is obtained. This completes the proof.
Note that a slight modification of the above proof obtains the following more general result.

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a non-degenerate interval. If $A$ and $B$ are two non-empty disjoint closed subsets of $I$ where at least one of them is bounded, then there is $\phi \in C^{\infty}(I)$ such that $\phi (x) = 1$ for all $x\in A$, $\phi (x) = 0$ for all $x\in B$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$.

